# problems to config a gitlab-ci.yml file. config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

Tags: angular, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

Im trying to create my first CI on gitlab. I have a angular app, with nx-workspace (monorepo) and this is my fully ci file:

```
image: node:16-alpine
stages:
  - setup
  - test

install-dependencies:
  stage: setup
  only:
    - develop

.distributed:
  interruptible: true
  only:
    - develop
  needs: ["install-dependencies"]
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules/.cache/nx

workspace-lint:
  stage: test
  extends: .distributed
  script:
    - npx nx workspace-lint

format-check:
  stage: test
  extends: .distributed
  script:
    - npx nx format:check

lint:
  stage: test
  extends: .distributed
  script:
    - npx nx affected --base=HEAD~1 --target=lint --parallel=3

test:
  stage: test
  extends: .distributed
  script:
    - npx nx affected --base=HEAD~1 --target=test --parallel=3 --ci --code-coverage

build:
  stage: test
  extends: .distributed
  script:
    - npx nx affected --base=HEAD~1 --target=build --parallel=3
```

Git lab shows this error:

This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs install-dependencies config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

The example are offered by nx docs. Im doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs install-dependencies config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

You need to add a `script:` block to `install-dependencies`

```
install-dependencies:
  stage: setup
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - yarn install # or whatever you need to install your deps
```

Otherwise, you would have the job `install-dependencies` defined, but you have no instructions for what that job should do.

Comment: thx my friend. thats it!