# How do i pass inputs to a template file in gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, cicd

I have a template file for my before_scripts

common-scripts.gitlab-ci.yaml

```
spec:
  input:
    branchName: 
      default: "main"

default:
  before_script:
    - git clone git@gitlab.eng.xyz.com:msp/abc-devops-infra.git --sparse --no-checkout --depth 1
    - cd abc-devops-infra
    - git sparse-checkout set "cicd/scripts" --no-cone
    - git checkout $[[ inputs.branchName ]]
    - source cicd/scripts/pipeline.sh
```

and i've included it in another file to extend and complete the template (nested include)

*another-template.gitlab-ci.yaml*

```
  - local: '/templates/.common-scripts.gitlab-ci.yaml'
      inputs:
        branchName: "XYZ"
```

and finally *common-scripts.gitlab-ci.yaml* gets included in the actually repository.
but the problem I'm facing is, gitci complains about.

```
jobs spec config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword
```

no idea about how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that a job called `spec` has incorrectly defined config since no `script` or `trigger` keyword is present.

You need to separate the `spec:input` headers in `common-scripts.gitlab-ci.yaml` from the remainder of your code using a triple hyphen `---` [1]. In this case, GitLab is interpreting the headers as a `job` called `spec` that is being defined without a required `trigger` or `script` [2] section as follows:

```yaml
spec:
  input:
    branchName: 
      default: "main"
---

default:
  before_script:
    - git clone git@gitlab.eng.xyz.com:msp/abc-devops-infra.git --sparse --no-checkout --depth 1
    - cd abc-devops-infra
    - git sparse-checkout set "cicd/scripts" --no-cone
    - git checkout $[[ inputs.branchName ]]
    - source cicd/scripts/pipeline.sh
```

---

[1] https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/inputs.html#define-input-parameters-with-specinputs

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/72106452/11257137